# wamp doesn't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing

Tags: wamp, wampserver, msvcr100.dll

When I start `Wampserver 3.0.0` I get the message `"wamp can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing"`, this is despite my having downloaded `vcredist_x64` `(Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable x64)` from Microsoft site for my `64 bit machine` and having installed it. Any suggestion as to what else I should do?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51417613/4799599) too. Packed above files in one place.

Answer (score 16):

You have not followed the prerequisites that are displayed BEFORE installation begins. You have not read and validated Next. Yet the text is very explicit

**--- Installation of Wampserver -**--

BEFORE proceeding with the installation of Wampserver, you must ensure that certain elements are installed on your system, otherwise Wampserver will absolutely not run, and in addition, the installation will be faulty and you need to remove Wampserver BEFORE installing the elements that were missing.

Make sure you are "up to date" in the redistributable packages VC9, VC10, VC11, VC13 and VC14
Even if you think you are up to date, install each package as administrator and if message "Already installed", validate Repair.

The following packages (VC9, VC10, VC11) are imperatively required to Wampserver 2.4, 2.5 and 3.0, even if you use only Apache and PHP versions VC11 and VC14 is required for PHP 7 and Apache 2.4.17

**-- VC9 Packages (Visual C++ 2008 SP1)**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092

-- VC10 Packages (Visual C++ 2010 SP1)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523

**-- VC11 Packages (Visual C++ 2012 Update 4)**

The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

**-- VC13 Packages[/b] (Visual C++ 2013[)**

The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

**-- VC14 Packages (Visual C++ 2015)**

The two files vcredist_x86.exe and vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:

http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=48145

If you have a 64-bit Windows, you must install both 32 and 64bit versions, even if you do not use Wampserver 64 bit.

This is item number 20 of TROUBLESHOOTING TIPS of Wampserver
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915

This text is in the file install-directory_of_wampserver/install-english.txt

Comment: First two links not available anymore