# WampServer - mysqld.exe can't start because MSVCR120.dll is missing

Tags: mysql, wordpress, windows-7, vmware, wampserver

I've tried to run wampserver on my local side, but mysql server doesn't run. 
when I try to **install service**, it give me error. I searched the answer all day and found some answers on here and there.

but any solution doesn't work for me. I tried to install warpserver on windows7 home OS vmware

Any help for me?

Comment: If you read the FIRST DIALOG that the install presents you with, you will see that it TELLS YOU that you must install a set of MSVC RUntime Libraries. See [the WAMPServer 3 All you need to know](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295) On the WAMPServer site

Comment: Links to downloadable Runtime libraries are available on the WAMPServer Backup Repo [which can be found here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) Look at the bottom of that page

Comment: If you are using the 64bit WAMPServer, please remember you need the 32bit AND 64bit MSVC Runtimes installed

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I finally found solution to fix my problem.
I've tried several ways to fix above problem and but nothing work for me.

As you know, WampServer use some visual c++ redistributable packs to run. And it makes user confuse which version of it should be installed (at least in my case)

After struggling few hours to fix it, I found good software - **check_vcredist** which guide wampserver installation easily.

http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/tools/check_vcredist.exe

Before you install WampServer, you'll get all information what you're missing on your laptop now if you run this software. Please follow it's notice. then WampServer will be installed successfully.

I hope this answer give some help to someone who is stealing his time to install WampServer.

Answer (score 86):

None of answers in google worked for me . This is how I solved my problem :

According to [Wampserver forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295) you must install ALL versions of Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable(2008 , 2010 , 2012 , 2013 , 2015 , 2017 ... ) . So you have to download them one by one and then **install all** of them (Not just **one/latest** ) .

I've already packed them [here (x86)](https://files.drax.ir/wampserver/vcredist_x86_Allversions.zip) and [here (x64)](https://files.drax.ir/wampserver/vcredist_x64_Allversions.zip). Just download and extract them then install all distributions at once then restart your Windows and run Wampserver.

Alternatively, you could download the full package from Microsoft's official page:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

That's it!

Comment: this is the saddest thing I have ever heard related to software. people have been shot for less

Comment: Haven't been back to Windows for a while, and thought I'd do some web programming. This post has made me switch back to Linux and burn my Windows discs.

Comment: Well, I guess I have to agree with you. Though there are far easier solutions to work web programming in Windows these days. Try https://laragon.org/docs/

Comment: Installing all versions of Microsoft Visual C/C++ Redistributable fixed the issue for me.

Comment: omg, it worked! by the way, it couldn't install 2015.exe from .zip, so I've downloaded latest file from Microsoft.

Comment: Great answer, it works perfectly on two Win10 machines where I need old Laravel 5 so also PHP 5.6. Thank you!

Comment: links dont work anymore. this should help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54110615/got-msvcr120-dll-missing-wamp-error-while-installing-wamp-on-windows-10-os

Answer (score 7):

Download visual c++ redistributable packs and install

Link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Restart and it should work

Comment: I recommend Linux it's best

Comment: And thats the WRONG MSVC Runtime to install MSCVR120

Comment: Sorry updated with recommend link from wampserver website

Answer (score 3):

You should install the following packages:

1. Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 (11.0)
2. Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 (12.0)
3. Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 (14.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it works for me after facing bunch of attempts

*Solution for Wamp server problem(msvcp120.dll or msvcp120.dll or any other missing file)*

1. *Install*  wamp server
2. if the problem encounters as *msvcp120.dll or any other file missing*
3. *search* for the particular file with correct system ( *whether 32 or 64bit* ) size, then *download* the particular missing file, the file size is about ( *0.5 - 0.95 MB* )
4. then *extract* the file and *paste* it in (local  disk=>windows=>search for name as *system 32 or 64*)and click it.
5. then it'll show the list of files, in that location, paste the extracted file within the particular *system 32 or 64*
6. then *uninstall the wamp server*)
7. After that must *shut down* your  PC
8. then *turn on* PC
9. *reinstall* *wamp server* .

Atlast, no problem will exist and green icon will also be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Solved just installing:

- Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019: x64 https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe
- Visual Studio 2013 (VC++ 12.0):  https://aka.ms/highdpimfc2013x64enu
- Visual Studio 2012 (VC++ 11.0): https://download.my.visualstudio.com/db/en_visual_cpp_redistributable_for_visual_studio_2012_update_4_x64_3161523.exe?t=4e421644-264c-4b19-b362-eab41d52c831&e=1607795665&h=5bc66a728d26f6912200e633437ad9a9&su=1

And then, wampserver3.2.3_x64.exe

Answer (score 0):

step 1 :
download [check_vcredist.exe](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/tools/check_vcredist.exe) and run it.
now you can see what you don't have.

step 2 :
download what you don't have from [here](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) and install them.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with logic, I saw that the problem was with mysqld (MYSQL oracle in 3306), then I looked for the mysql 5.7 requirementes in the official page, and was vcredist c++ 2013 and downloaded, installed and solved. Only uninstall and reinstall wamp. But vcredist c++ 2013 was the solution for me for wamp 3.2.3 version.

Answer (score -1):

download the missing file from

https://www.dll-files.com/msvcp120.dll.html

Add the file to C:\Windows\System32

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).