# Got msvcr120.dll missing wamp error while installing wamp on windows 10 OS

Tags: wampserver

I tried to setup wamp in my windows 64 bit operating system form the below link

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

While setting up it is alerting `msvcr120.dll missing wamp` error.

Can any one provide how could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing at least one of Microsofts MSVC C/C++ Runtime libraries required to run Apache/PHP or MySQL.

Look [here on the WAMPServer backup repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) Down at the bottom you will find a link called

```
All VC Redistribuable Packages (x86_x64) (32 & 64bits)
```

Download that ZIP file, it contains all the needed installs for all the needed MSVC Runtimes.

Unzip it, then run each MSVC Runtime version install One-at-a-Time in logical version number order, oldest first.
If you see a dialog saying that the version is installed click the REPAIR button to make sure its correctly installed.

As you are using a 64bit windows and a 64bit WAMPServer, you MUST install BOTH the 32bit AND 64bit MSVC Runtimes.

> Once all these are installed, uninstall WAMPServer, manually delete the `C:\wamp64` folder and then reinstall WAMPServer. This is required to be absolutely sure that the install works correctly, as without these MSVC Runtimes parts of the install can fail.

*Small Note*

> The first dialog shown by the Install does actually tell you to make sure these runtime libraries are installed before continuing with the install.

Comment: this helped me by installing almost all

Answer (score 0):

During install u after 2 nd step focus on the 3rd step download all link software which start from c++ in it download all which is available and skip when u see error or file not found after all install done u should do further process and its done

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).